# What does "pack a buck for miles" mean?

Tags: idioms, american-english, dialects

I am reading "[Where the Crawdads sing](https://www.deliaowens.com/crawdads-excerpt)" and I stumbled upon this sentence "pack a buck for miles".
Does this mean some money (e.g., US dollar)?

> "The Land . . . being marshy and Swamps, we return'd towards our Ship . . . Discouragement of all such as should hereafter come into those Parts to settle."
>
> Those looking for serious land moved on, and this infamous marsh
> became a net, scooping up a mishmash of mutinous sailors, castaways,
> debtors, and fugitives dodging wars, taxes, or laws that they didn't
> take to. The ones malaria didn't kill or the swamp didn't swallow bred
> into a woodsmen tribe of several races and multiple cultures, each of
> whom could fell a small forest with a hatchet and **pack a buck** for
> miles. Like river rats, each had his own territory, yet had to fit
> into the fringe or simply disappear some day in the swamp. Two hundred
> years later, they were joined by runaway slaves, who escaped into the
> marsh and were called maroons, and freed slaves, penniless and
> beleaguered, who dispersed into the water-land because of scant
> options.

Answer (score 2):

A discussion on Reddit some years ago suggests that “pack a buck” means carry a male deer, as animals killed for food needed to be transported to wherever they were to be processed.

A few paragraphs later, it’s noted that this swamp-land area included “fatted deer.”